# void* as generic in C, is it safe?

Tags: c, generics

get ready for a question a bit "twisted"...

I've implemented in the past a lot of data structure (tree, list, hash table, graph as well), using the macro i can implement some kind o generic. However i was wandering if it is possible to implement generic data structure using void pointer but somehow i would like to be able to use a typecheking...

I don't know if it is clear what i'm trying to say... but basically i don't think it is always safe to put "void*" as generic, at the same time i don't think is always a good idea to use the macro as way to make a generic data structure (since basically what a preprocessor does with the macro does is code substitution), because if you look around the web you can find such examples.

A good idea might be, in my opinion but probably i'm not right, is to use the macro for make a standard interface for the data stored in a data structure, among the interface functions i would put code for correct type checking, given a void*. Inspired by the software engineer techinique this could be a good way to proceed.

It is surely true that probably for too sofisticated stuff would be better to switch language (C++/Java) but it is even true that this is not always possible.

So in summary... how the problem of "generic" in C is usually handled? i rely on your experience for an answer!

Comment: You can use `void *` as  a generic pointer, but you must also store information about what is being pointed to, if you want to actually retrieve that.

Comment: I never liked `void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*))`, but there's truly not a better to do the job. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm

Comment: it's not twisted at all. it's a wide spread usage to implement generic ds using `void *` to point to another block of data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Briefly, there’s no convenient way to get type-safe generic data structures and functions in C.

Non-generic:

```
struct node {
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};
```

Generic, but unsafe—a `void*` has no type information:

```
struct node {
  void *value;
  struct node *next;
};
```

Safe, but ugly:

```
#define DECLARE_NODE_TYPE(type) \
  struct node_##type { \
    type value; \
    struct node_##type *next; \
  };

DECLARE_NODE_TYPE(int)
node_int *x = ...
```

Same idea, but slightly less ugly:

```
// declare_node_type.h

struct node_##NODE_TYPE {
  NODE_TYPE value;
  struct node_##NODE_TYPE *next;
};

#undef NODE_TYPE

// elsewhere

#define NODE_TYPE int
#include "declare_node_type.h"

node_int *x = ...
```

Generic and safe, but C++, not C:

```
template<typename T>
struct node {
  T value;
  node<T> *next;
};

node<int> *x = ...
```

Comment: the third way is generally not recommended. it generated a bunch of code that may not get called. `void *` is a better way.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: It’s a tradeoff. If you want safety, you also have to ensure that you aren’t generating unused code, or at least that you’re stripping unused symbols and coalescing duplicate symbols in the binary. This is true in C++ as well.

Comment: I've seen that third way used a lot. I'd say it's almost the standard way to do templates in C.

Comment: So is "safe but ugly" definitely the common way to do template in C?

Comment: @Lukkio: Yes, basically. Either you use a macro, or you use `#include`: the preprocessor is the standard way to do code generation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do *safer* stuff with `void*`; getting back to the linked example of Jon Purdy:

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        void* data;  // generic data
        int idata;   // int is not stored dynamically
    };
    int type;    // additional type information
    Node* next;  // link
} Node;

#define NODE_TYPE_INT 0
Node* createNodeInt(Node* self, Node* next, int value) {
    self->idata = value;
    self->type = NODE_TYPE_INT;
    self->next = next;
    return self;
}

// in this case relying on user defined types...
Node* createNodeGeneric(Node* self, Node* next, void* data, int type) {
    assert(type != NODE_TYPE_INT && ..);
    self->data = data;
    self->type = type;
    self->next = next;
    return self;
}
```

Another approach is to use the common first member as the base type:

```
typedef struct {
    int type;
} Node;

#define TYPE_BINARY 0
typedef struct {
    Node base;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    int op;
} BinaryOp;

#define TYPE_LEAF_INT 1
typedef struct {
    Node base;
    int a;
} LeafInt;

#define TYPE_LEAF_FLOAT 2
typedef struct {
    Node base;
    float b;
} LeafFloat;

void op(BinaryOp* node) {
    switch(node->left.type) {
    case TYPE_BINARY:
        op((BinaryOp*)node->left);
        break;
    case TYPE_LEAF_INT:
        evalInt((LeafInt*)node->left);
        break;
    ...
    }
}

Node* foo() {
    LeafInt* left;
    LeafFloat* right;
    BinaryOp* op;
    // allocate
    ...
    // init
    createLeafInt(left, 42);
    createLeafFloat(right, 13.37);
    createBinaryOp(op, &left->base, &right->base);
    // and return
    return &op->base;
}
}
```

Comment: This is a way to store the info together with the data, but i want i meant was something like "this list can only store this type here" i just would like to pass the data, and internally the logic of the list should be such that the check is provided.

Comment: @Lukkio this is exactly the way you provide an API that does the checking - but the checking happens on the client side, by calling the right function into the API or providing the necessary data for the data structure (`type` simply is part of your data)